# cannot be safely interpreted as an integer in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying with with this code
`a=np.logspace(-1,np.log10(10,),11.)[::-1]`
but getting error as below
TypeError: object of type <class 'float'> cannot be safely interpreted as an integer.

Answer (score 3):

You passed `11.` as `num`, which is supposed to be an integer. `11.` is a `float` literal; remove the `.` to make it `11`, an `int` literal.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logspace.html), the third argument to `np.logspace` is the "Number of samples to generate". In your code, `np.logspace(-1,np.log10(10,),11.)` the third argument is `11.`, which is a floating-point number, but an integer is required, like `11`, without the decimal point.